# How to work with dynamic objects as input for lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, lambda, expandoobject

I want to store expression in a database in order to maintain a rule engine. The expressions are in the form of this example:

```
Expression<Func<MyTerm, bool>> expression = t => t.MyProperty == SomeValue;
```

The problem I am facing is that I have to create MyTerm at runtime. In order to still be able to use MyTerm as a parameter for a lambda expression, I implemented a solution with ExpandoObject, like so:

```
public class MyTerm
{
    ExpandoObject ParameterSet;

    public void AddParameter(string name, object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = ParameterSet as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            dictionary[name] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary.Add(name, value);
        }
    }

    public string GetString(string name)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = ParameterSet as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            return (string)dictionary[name];
        }
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("Term does not contain parameter {name}.");
    }
```

The thing is, I gain the advantage of being able to add parameters at runtime to MyTerm, but I have to specify the return type for each getter, instead of being able to use the syntax above:

```
t.MyProperty
```

Is there a way to use dynamic objects as input for lambda expressions or are there ways to write an extension method for classes like this in order to return an object and not a specific type? I am able to compile expressions like so:

```
public static Func<MyTerm, bool> Compile(string body)
{
    ParameterExpression term = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyTerm), typeof(MyTerm).Name);
    LambdaExpression exp = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { term }, typeof(bool), body);
    return (Func<DynamicTerm, bool>)exp.Compile();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyTerm term = new MyTerm();
    term.AddParameter("SomeParameter", "SomeValue");

    Func<MyTerm, bool> IsGreaterThanSomeParameter = Compile("MyTerm.GetString(\"SomeParameter\")== SomeValue);

    bool result = IsGreaterThanSomeParameter(term);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I want to store lambda expressions that are independent from a specific implementation, so if another service tries to compile these expressions back to a function, the syntax should be usable out of the box. Without any workaroung getters.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I still don't follow: 1) how you're storing expressions in a database, 2) how ParameterSet relates to MyTerm, 3) why you're trying to use a dynamic at all. If your expression is fixed, it only ever accesses a known set of properties on MyTerm, so you don't need to dynamically add properties, surely?

Comment: 1) It's not really related to the problem I am facing. I just wanted to give context to the application. 2) ParameterSet is an ExpandoObject that gives me the ability to add parameter at runtime to the class MyTerm. 3) My expression is fixed. But not my set of possible expressions. Parameters can be added to MyTerm as well as expressions can be added relating to those parameters

Comment: But you're not adding properties at runtime to `MyTerm`. You've added a `GetString` method which happens to use an `ExpandoObject` as a dictionary, but you never call `GetString`. You don't use `dynamic` anywhere.

Comment: I added my AddParameter method. This is the method I use to add parameters at runtime

Comment: You still don't have anything that calls `GetString`, and you're still not using the `ExpandoObject` as anything other than a `Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete sample. I edited again.

Comment: What is `DynamicTerm`? You're still just using `ExpandoObject` as a dictionary -- you could replace it with a dictionary and nothing would change.

Comment: DynamicTerm was a typo. It should be MyTerm. This is the first time I am using Expandoobject, so I thought that's it. Am I not adding properties to the expandoobject in addParameters?

Comment: Normally you use `ExpandoObject` with the `dynamic` keyword -- `dynamic x = new ExpandoObject(); x.Foo = "Bar";`. You're just using it as a Dictionary, and you could (and should) just use a Dictionary instead

Comment: Got it. So essentially, there is no way to use a dynamic object as input for a lambda expression right?

Comment: No. But, you're using expressions. You can easily rewrite them however you like. You can easily start with an expression for `obj.Id == 3`, and rewrite that to say `obj.Get<int>("Id") == 3`. The tricky thing is how you know that `Id` has type `int`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So essentially I have to maintain some sort of mapping from name to type, of course. Instead of dragging this syntax into the expression it may be cleaner to just use expressions that operate on a specific parameter instead of an object that represents a whole set of parameters and store the relations outside of the expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if your object has an indexer on it, System.Linq.Dynamic will try and call it if it doesn't find a matching property.

```
public class DynamicTerm
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> store = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void Set(string key, object value) => store[key] = value;
    public object this[string key] => store[key];
}

public static void Main()
{
    string body = "Term.SomeProperty == \"foo\"";
    ParameterExpression termExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DynamicTerm), "Term");
    var exp = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { termExpr }, typeof(bool), body);
    var compiled = (Func<DynamicTerm, bool>)exp.Compile();

    var term = new DynamicTerm();
    term.Set("SomeProperty", "foo");

    Console.WriteLine(compiled(term));
}
```

I can't find a way of returning *typed* data (it converts both sides to object): it works with strings however. Perhaps it's a starting point.

Comment: Yeas that's a great start. But I think in order for me to get this to work I would need something like this: public T this<T>[string key]{get { /* Return generic type T. */ }}

Comment: Indeed, and I couldn't find a way to do that. How are you using your `DynamicTerm` -- are you only ever accessing properties off it and doing binary comparisons? Or do you do something more complex? One option is to do what's in my answer, then use an `ExpressionVisitor` to turn `Term.SomeProperty == (object)"foo"` into `(string)Term.SomeProperty == "foo"`

Comment: Actually I am only using DynamicTerm as a wrapper for my parameters in order to do some simple checks. The problem is, that I want to be able to use multiple parameters in connected expressions. Something like (t.Age >= 10 || t.Name == "Tom")

Comment: Where `t` is your DynamicTerm?

Comment: ah yes. Sorry I keep mixing up names.